# How to add the Default data from Ldif file to the Ldap Server with the java api?

Tags: java, spring-boot-test, spring-ldap, ldif

I need to add bulk data into the LDAP server from the ldif file. I researched of java APIs but can't find the suitable one

I already tried with LdapTestUtils but it requires a server restart. I need another way except this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can also be achieved via LdapTemplate. LdapParser will parse the record from ldif file in the form of LdapAttribute then bind this record via ldapTemplate.bind

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();

        contextSource.setUrl("ldap://192.168.99.101:389/");
        contextSource.setUserDn("uid=admin,dc=abc,dc=com");
        contextSource.setPassword(********);
        contextSource.setPooled(false);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        LdapTemplate template = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        LdifParser parser = new LdifParser(new ClassPathResource("schema.ldif"));
        parser.open();
        while (parser.hasMoreRecords()) {
            LdapAttributes record = parser.getRecord();
            LdapName dn = record.getName();
            template.bind(dn, null, record);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a separate library that has API supporting LDIF import. Once such library is [Apache Directory LDAP API](https://directory.apache.org/api/). The library is in general compatible with most of the LDAP servers.

Refer the [documentation](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/gen-docs/2.0.0-M9/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/directory/server/core/api/CoreSession.html), The LdifFileLoader class has features to import LDIF, in tandem with DefaultDirectoryService class (unfortunately I am unable to locate my earlier code demonstrating the LDIF import). You could refer [this post](https://coderanch.com/t/612184/java/ApacheDS-import-ldif-file), which shows how to use the above, though it deals with a problem of a different type.

I am not sure of the LDAP server you are using, however, you could give the above a shot and check.